# Get exact inner html from buttons that you click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Soo i want, like i have 11 buttons and i want for each of them when i click to get a console.log about their text
like i have button called books. and when i click it to show books in console and soo on other buttons
and i want to do a navbar with dropdown bar but with js
soo when i click certain button it shows dropdown and with X and right up corner and when i click it to close that menu(dropdown)

Hope someone can help me

I got array of elements but again idk how to list them and do what I want

```js
const opennav = () => {
  let menu = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content');
  let button = document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn');

  const buttonTextsArray = [];
  let buttonTexts = document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn');
  buttonTexts.forEach(button => {
    buttonTextsArray.push(button.innerHTML);
  });
  console.log(buttonTextsArray);
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* background: linear-gradient(0.14turn, #db408b, #bd3a79, #18de9f);*/
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(0.14turn, #db408b, #bd3a79, #18de9f);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/*.dropbtn{
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
} 
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
} */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.dropdown-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdownimg {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-color: linear-gradient(0.14turn, #db408b, #bd3a79, #18de9f);
}

.opis {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slika {
  /* slika za wall art*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
}

.flex-container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  border-color: linear-gradient(0.14turn, #db408b, #bd3a79, #18de9f);
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.footercontainer {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-color: linear-gradient(0.14turn, #db408b, #bd3a79, #18de9f);
}

.footerimg {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
}

.vertical-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  align-items: center;
}

.footertitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
}

.footeropis {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.invisibleline hr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.invisibleline2 hr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.invisibleline3 hr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}


/*Canvas prints special mode */

.canvasprintstitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.canvasprintsbutton {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #18de9f;
  background: transparent;
}

.canvasspecialimage {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
}

.containerforcanvas {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 10%;
  border-color: linear-gradient(0.14turn, #db408b, #bd3a79, #18de9f);
}

.invisibleverticalline {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="opennav()">books</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="kartica">
        <img class="slika" src="Standard Hardcovers.png">
        <div class="title">Standard Hardcovers</div>
        <div class="opis">
          <a href="#">A4 & A3 Personalised Photo Books - Standard Hardcover</a>
          <a href="#">A4 Classic Photo Book - Standard Hardcover</a>
          <a href="#">Little Moments Photo Book</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="kartica">
        <img class="slika" src="Premium Hardcover.png">
        <div class="title">Premium Hardcover</div>
        <div class="opis">
          <a href="#">A4 & A3 Personalised Photo Books - Standard Hardcover</a>
          <a href="#">A4 Classic Photo Book - Standard Hardcover</a>
          <a href="#">Little Moments Photo Book</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="kartica">
        <img class="slika" src="CutOut Cover Books.png">
        <div class="title">CutOut Cover Books</div>
        <div class="opis">
          <a href="#">A4 Year Photo Books - Special Edition</a>
          <a href="#">Circle Window Cutout - Photo Book</a>
          <a href="#">A4 Classic Collage Book  </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="kartica">
        <img class="slika" src="By Ocassion.png">
        <div class="title">By Ocassion</div>
        <div class="opis">
          <a href="#">Wedding Photo Books</a>
          <a href="#">Travel Photo Books</a>
          <a href="#">Birthday Photo Books </a>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="kartica">
        <img class="slika" src="Books for loved one.png">
        <div class="title">Books for loved one</div>
        <div class="opis">
          <a href="#">Baby Photo Books</a>
          <a href="#">Photo Albums for Couples</a>
          <a href="#">Pet Photo Books</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div class="invisibleline">
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="footercontainer">
        <div class="footercontent">
          <img class="footerimg" src="fast-delivery.png">
          <div class="footerverticalline"></div>
          <div class="footertitle">Quick delivery</div>
          <div class="footeropis">
            <hr>
            <p>Hundreds of gifts dispatched daily</p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="footercontainer">
        <div class="footercontent">
          <img class="footerimg" src="Quality.png">
          <div class="footerverticalline"></div>
          <div class="footertitle">Quality prints</div>
          <div class="footeropis">
            <hr>
            <p>We keep it premium | products | prints</p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="footercontainer">
        <div class="footercontent">
          <img class="footerimg" src="smartphone.png">
          <div class="footerverticalline"></div>
          <div class="footertitle">Easy to use</div>
          <div class="footeropis">
            <hr>
            <p>Create photo gifts in a minutes</p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="footercontainer">
        <div class="footercontent">
          <img class="footerimg" src="assistant.png">
          <div class="footerverticalline"></div>
          <div class="footertitle">24/7 Support</div>
          <div class="footeropis">
            <hr>
            <p>Contact us any time you have a question.</p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dont mind if you find some abnormal errors in coding im begginer :))